# The search bar of the Globe Buildir plugin gives no result?

Tags: qgis-plugins

As in the photo I'm clicking on the search button but nothing happens. The other globe centering selections are working well except "Geocoding". What might be the problem ?

QGIS 3.28.15

[image]